wxWebRequest crashes at Release but works in Debug
I am using wxWebRequest to download a very small (1 KB) text file from the server with the following code:
auto WebRequest = wxWebSession::GetDefault().CreateRequest(this,
"https://www.pebytes.com/downloads/version.txt");
WebRequest.Start();

Bind(wxEVT_WEBREQUEST_STATE, &frmMacroLand::OnCheckNewVersion, this);

In Debug version all works well, but in Release version the application crashes and the event handler function is not even called:
void frmMacroLand::OnCheckNewVersion(wxWebRequestEvent &event)
{
    switch (event.GetState())
    {
        case wxWebRequest::State_Completed:
        wxInputStream* Input = event.GetResponse().GetStream();
        wxTextInputStream text(*Input );
    
        std::string str;
        while(Input->IsOk() && !Input->Eof()) //crashes here

The crash happens in mutex library in:
 void lock() {
        if (_Mtx_lock(_Mymtx()) != _Thrd_result::_Success) {
            // undefined behavior, only occurs for plain mutexes (N4950 [thread.mutex.requirements.mutex.general]/6)
            _STD _Throw_Cpp_error(_RESOURCE_DEADLOCK_WOULD_OCCUR);
        }

Any ideas?
By the way, I am using Windows 11 with MSVC and wxWidgets 3.2

where exactly the crash occur?  Can you try and isolate it? Also - does it at least start the download?

It doesn't even call the event handler function, so no download at all.  The frame shows and then immediately crashes. However, in Debug version all works as expected.

Can you do a release build with debug info and run it in a debugger ?

@macroland, or just try going to basics - put couple of printf's...

@AhmedAEK, I have run a release build with debug info and updated the question.

@Igor: No need for printf, the release build with debug info was really helpful to pinpoint the crash (learned something :) )

@AhmedAEK, The problem was actually the std::promise that I was using to capture the downloaded text and process it with another std::thread. In debug all worked well but in release it crashed. Moving all processing code right after the while solved my problem but still not sure why such a difference in both builds.

You might be running into this notorious issue.

Not so sure but I think that might be the case as I was using not a fairly new "msvcp140.dll" file.
